# Why doesn't Hadoop file system support random I/O?

Tags: file-io, filesystems, hadoop, distributed-system, gfs

The distributed file systems which like Google File System and Hadoop doesn't support random I/O.
(It can't modify the file which were written before. Only writing and appending is possible.)

Why did they design file system like this?
What are the important advantages of the design?

P.S I know Hadoop will support modifing the data which were written.
But they said, it's performance will very not good. Why?

Comment: If you optimize for one particular case, you want that one to be fast. Things not consiered may then suffer in performance. For example I once wrote a `RowSet` implementation in Java that operated on a CSV file. I needed random access there and was roughly four times slower in seeking to the last line of the file than a `BufferedReader` which can only read forwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hadoop distributes and replicates files. Since the files are replicated, any write operation is going to have to find each replicated section across the network and update the file. This will heavily increase the time for the operation. Updating the file could push it over the block size and require the file split into 2 blocks, and then replicating the 2nd block. I don't know the internals and when/how it would split a block... but it's a potential complication.

What if the job failed or got killed which already did an update and gets re-run? It could update the file multiple times.

The advantage of not updating files in a distributed system is that you don't know who else is using the file when you update it, you don't know where the pieces are stored. There are potential time outs (node with the block is unresponsive) so you might end up with mismatched data (again, I don't know the internals of hadoop and an update with a node down might be handled, just something I'm brainstorming)

There are a lot of potential issues (a few laid out above) with updating files on the HDFS. None of them are insurmountable, but they will require a performance hit to check and account for.

Since the HDFS's main purpose is to store data for use in mapreduce, row level update isn't that important at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the block size of the data and the whole idea of Hadoop is that you don't move data around but instead you move the algorithm to the data.

Hadoop is designed for non-realtime batch processing of data. If you're looking at ways of implementing something more like a traditional RDBMS in terms of response time and random access have a look at [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) which is built on top of Hadoop.

Comment: right, MapReduce doesn't need to have random access. It doesn't fit into the paradigm.