# How to insert a line to the beginning of a file in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Hadoop program in which I need to add a couple of line to the beginning of the reducer's output file (when it's done) in my Java program. I'm using the following code

```
 RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(new File("/user/hzakerza/graph/output9/part-r-00000"), "rw");
 f.seek(0);             
 f.writeChars("some line");
 f.close();
```

However it gives me an error that the file does not exist. How can I insert a few lines to this file within my Java program?

Comment: "Append" specifically implies _add to the end._ Just sayin'.

Comment: Are you doing this after the job returns? Is this in your driver file?

Comment: yes, when the reducer is done.

Comment: `RandomAccessFile` may be accessing the local filesystem and not HDFS

Comment: Btw check these links,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769394/why-doesnt-hadoop-file-system-support-random-i-o

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/200811.mbox/%3C4aa34eb70811131511h4382bf46rfb65ef0f86e755b@mail.gmail.com%3E